# SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) Laravel in production

Tags: php, laravel

Well, basically I got this error when I moved my project from local to production. In local it works perfectly. At first I thought Laravel wasn't reading .env, so I hardcoded the access data in database.php, but anything changed. I'm in a shared hosting and I don't hace access to the console. Any ideas?

Comment: does the username and password the same in your database in the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it doesn't pick up .env, it could means it's reading directly from the cached config. Changing `database.php` wouldn't help because config has been cached.

In your production file manager, look for `/bootstrap/cache/config.php` and delete it. It will manually clear the config cache on your production server and laravel should now picking up database configuration string from .env again.

Comment: Yep it's when you don't have access to the console. If you have access to it, you can do `php artisan config:clear` to clear it. Or `config:cache` to clear and cache it again.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick for you.

```
 php artisan config:clear
```